# GitLab, dind and docker-compose and unkown flag c (context)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, docker-in-docker

I maked pipeline in GitLab with docker:20.10-dind image.
When i tried run:

```
 - docker-compose -c remote pull best-ever-app
```

I saw next:

> unknown shorthand flag: 'c' in -c

If I use --context same thing.

I tried to install docker-compose in image in these ways:

```
    - curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.15.1/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    - ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

and

```
 - apk add docker-compose
```

No way helped.

On my local computer docker-compose with flag "c" work good.
Whats problem in docker container?

Answer (score 0):

Local I had 1.29.2 docker-compose.
docker-compose v2 work that:

> DOCKER_HOST="ssh://admin@172.31.31.30" docker-compose pull
> best-ever-app